# Spreadsheetgear chart x-axis text orientation

Tags: c#, .net, charts, spreadsheetgear

I am using Spreadsheetgear to create and modify charts.  I can create a chart and modify the data easily, however, I cannot seem to modify the orientation of text the way that I want.

The text lies on the x-axis and I am trying to get it to display at a 45 degree angle.  I can do this manually by right clicking on the chart and manually setting the orientation angle to 45, but I want to do this using C#.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IChart chart = ...;
chart.Axes[SpreadsheetGear.Charts.AxisType.Category].TickLabels.Orientation = 45;
```